# ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes from collect call

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00932

I got really happy when I was able to aggregation the results in one line using `cast(collect(value) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY)`, as in this example:

```
select site, lote, material, cast(collect(value) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS valueagg
from table1
GROUP BY site, lote, material, status;

SITE   LOTE    MA VALUEAGG
------ ------- -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAKI01 0000443 HW SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('9362','10k','1st','USERS','8','100MW','2','V2','CELL')
```

But when I try another aggregation over the results of that first query like `cast(collect(valueagg) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY)` I get an error, as in this example:

```
SELECT site, material, cast(collect(valueagg) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS valueagg2
FROM table1_agg -- result of first query
GROUP BY site, material;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

I tried to convert to varchar2 even though it would limit the result - I am not worried by this, as the first 4000 chars of the string would be enough for me - but I wasn't able to do this.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the relevant part of your code

Comment: select site, lote, material, cast(value) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS valueagg from (
table1
 )
GROUP BY site, lote, material

I  get

AAKI01, 0000443, HW, SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY(9362 CELL V2 2 100MW 8 USERS 1st 10K)

over this I do 

SELECT site, material, cast(collect(valueagg) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS valueagg2
  FROM    table1_agg
  GROUP BY site, material

and I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY` is a varray of varchar2, so your first query is fine; the `collect()` call gets a collection of strings, and it can cast that to a the `DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY` varray collection type.

Your second query is trying to create a collection of collections. [As the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions031.htm):

> If column is itself a collection, then the output of COLLECT is a nested table of collections.

What that `collect()` call is trying to create is a collection of collections of strings, and that is not the same type as `DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY`. You *could* create your own type to support that:

```
create type demo_type as varray(100) of DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY -- or as big as you need
/
```

And you can then do:

```
SELECT site, material, cast(collect(valueagg) as DEMO_TYPE) AS valueagg2
FROM table1_agg GROUP BY site, material;

SITE   MA VALUEAGG2
------ -- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAKI01 HW MYSCHEMA.DEMO_TYPE(PUBLIC.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('9362','10k','1st','USERS','8','100MW','2','V2','CELL'))
```

Or perhaps showing that more obviously with different `lote` values so your first query gets two rows:

```
select site, lote, material, cast(collect(value) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS valueagg
from table1 GROUP BY site, lote, material;

SITE   LOTE    MA VALUEAGG
------ ------- -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAKI01 0000443 HW SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('9362','8','100MW','2','V2','CELL')                                       
AAKI01 0000444 HW SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('USERS','10k','1st')

SELECT site, material, cast(collect(valueagg) as DEMO_TYPE) AS valueagg2
FROM table1_agg GROUP BY site, material;

SITE   MA VALUEAGG2
------ -- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAKI01 HW MYSCHEMA.DEMO_TYPE(PUBLIC.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('9362','8','100MW','2','V2','CELL'),PUBLIC.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('USERS','10k','1st'))
```

I'm not sure that's really what you want; I suspect you want a single collection containing the values from both aggregated values. That would mean unnesting them and recombining them:

```
SELECT site, material, cast(collect(column_value) as DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS valueagg2
FROM table1_agg CROSS JOIN TABLE(valueagg) v
GROUP BY site, material;

SITE   MA VALUEAGG2
------ -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAKI01 HW SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('9362','1st','10k','USERS','CELL','V2','2','100MW','8')
```

It might be simpler to just go back to the raw data and aggregate from scratch, since you're using a varray type which can't be used for a multiset operation.

Comment: Thanks man.  The "create type demo_type as varray(100) of DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY" solved it !!!
And used as cast(collect(valueagg) as DEMO_TYPE) 

Many thanks :-)